# Error: ./node_modules/angular-auth-oidc-client/fesm2015/angular-auth-oidc-client.js 4790:36-60 "export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable'

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, angular-auth-oidc-client

My angular version is 11 , and I am using latest version of `"angular-auth-oidc-client": "^12.0.1"`
It's not working for me, giving me the below error

> Error:
> ./node_modules/angular-auth-oidc-client/fesm2015/angular-auth-oidc-client.js 4835:24-48 "export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' (imported as 'i0') was not
> found in '@angular/core

Answer (score 0):

the version 12 of the lib is not compatible to Angular V11. So either you update your Angular app or you refer to the lib V11.